# Swagger-UI (Docker) - does not maintain base path when "Try it out"

Tags: docker, jax-rs, swagger, swagger-ui

I have a JAX-RS Application thats exports a openapi.json with Swagger2:

`http://localhost:8080/notification/rest/openapi.json`

And expose the OpenAPI:

```
{
  "openapi" : "3.0.1",
  "info" : {
    "title" : "Notification Module",
    "version" : "1.0"
  },
  "paths" : {
    "/sms/send" : {
      "post" : {
        "operationId" : "send_1",
        "requestBody" : {
          "content" : {
            "application/json" : {
              "schema" : {
                "$ref" : "#/components/schemas/Sms"
              }
            }
          }
        },
        "responses" : {
          "default" : {
            "description" : "default response",
            "content" : {
              "application/json" : {
                "schema" : {
                  "$ref" : "#/components/schemas/SendSmsResult"
                }
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }

    ...
  }
}
```

Now I'm trying to show the Swagger-UI in a Docker container:
`docker run -p 80:8080 -e URL="http://localhost:8080/notification/rest/openapi.json" swaggerapi/swagger-ui`

Swagger2 open normally. 
But the "Try it out" funcionallity it tries to request to:
`http://localhost:8080/sms/send`

Missing the context and base path `/notification/rest/`

**Is this possible to configure swagger-ui to create the URL request to:**
`http://localhost:8080/notification/rest/sms/send` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved.

Just configure the `servers` into `openapi-configuration.yaml` and works.

```
resourcePackages:
  - com.mycompany.app.rest
prettyPrint: true
cacheTTL: 0
buildContext: true
openAPI:
  servers:
    - url: http://localhost:8080/notification
  info:
    version: '1.0'
    title: Notification Module
```

Also, it's important to add a constructor with `@Context ServletConfig` parameter:

```
@ApplicationPath("/rest")
public class App extends Application {
    public App(@Context ServletConfig servletConfig) {
    }
}
```